# Should I index my mobile duplicate of my desktop website on google?

Tags: seo, google, mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a mobile version of site be considered duplication by Google if the page is the same only the css is different?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26073/can-a-mobile-version-of-site-be-considered-duplication-by-google-if-the-page-is)

I have a duplicate of `www.example.com` with the url `www.example.com/mobile` - all files are duplicated while the mobile version has a slightly different content. Notice that when I write 'mobile' I only mean regular HTML4 with smartphone friendly CSS. I have a series of redirects (using .htaccess) that allows smartphone users land directly on the mobile versions. But I wonder, shound I index the mobile version as well so those users will be able to get direct, faster links? And what is the proper way of doing that without causing problem in google search?

I guess I'm asking if there's a way to get google display regular urls for desktop users and ../mobile/.. urls for smartphone users, and if it is smart SEOwise.